# How to change angle mode in processing.js?

Tags: processing.js, degrees, radians, khan-academy

Khan Academy processing.js uses degrees as default for angle values, but you can modify it by:

```
angleMode("radians");
```

Processing.js uses radians as default, but the documentation refers to an angle mode (here as a parameter of rotate function):

> angle float: angle of rotation specified in radians or degrees
>   depending on the current angle mode

But I didn't find a function to change it. The code of the rotate function itself suggest that there is no degree mode:

```
Drawing2D.prototype.rotate = function(angleInRadians) {
  modelView.rotateZ(angleInRadians);
  modelViewInv.invRotateZ(angleInRadians);
  curContext.rotate(angleInRadians);
};
```

Is there a means to change the angle mode?

Comment: Yes. I overwrite the Khan Academy function before the with( processing) :   var rotateFn = processing.rotate; processing.rotate = function(angle) {       rotateFn(processing.radians(angle)); } You like full code?

Comment: I don't need to see the full code, but this question is still marked as "needs an answer", so I wanted to check with you to see if you still needed help.

Comment: I wrote the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the mode in the Khan processing.js (pjs) code itself. So you have to convert the values, as Ravi Sharma wrote in his answer.

As I didn't want to do that, to use Khan orginal programs as they are to run in normal processing.js / web environments, that's what I did:

(That is not only converting degrees to radians, but also the mouse and keyboard input)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
var processing = new Processing(canvas, function(processing) {
    processing.size(400, 400);
    processing.background(0,0,0,0);
    processing.sbShow = false;

    var mouseIsPressed = false;
    $(".container").on("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
        mouseIsPressed = true;
        processing.mouseX = e.pageX;
        processing.mouseY = e.pageY;
        processing.sbShow = false;
    }).on("mouseup touchend", function(e) {
        mouseIsPressed = false;
        processing.mouseX = e.pageX;
        processing.mouseY = e.pageY;
    }).on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
        processing.mouseX = e.pageX;
        processing.mouseY = e.pageY;
    });
    processing.mousePressed = function () { mouseIsPressed = true; };
    processing.mouseReleased = function () { mouseIsPressed = false; };

    var keyIsPressed = false;
    processing.keyPressed = function () { keyIsPressed = true; };
    processing.keyReleased = function () { keyIsPressed = false; };

    function getSound(s) {
        var url = "sounds/" + s + ".mp3";
        return new Audio(url);
    }

    function playSound(s) {
        s.play();
    }

    function getImage(s) {
        var url = "img/" + s + ".png";
        //processing.externals.sketch.imageCache.add(url);
        return processing.loadImage(url);
    }

    var rotateFn = processing.rotate;
    processing.rotate = function(angle) {
        rotateFn(processing.radians(angle));
    }
    var cosFn = processing.cos;
    processing.cos = function(angle) {
        return cosFn(processing.radians(angle));
    }
    var sinFn = processing.sin;
    processing.sin = function(angle) {
        return sinFn(processing.radians(angle));
    }

    with (processing) {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Insert original Khan academy pjs code (default is degrees) ...

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    };

    if (typeof draw !== 'undefined') processing.draw = draw;
});
```

Note: This is not complete. There are conversions missing for tan, atan, atan2 etc.

Comment: Do you have this on github? I'm using something similar and don't have the skills to fill in the rest of the missing features.

Comment: Actuall I think the code I'm using was originally copied from you.

Comment: No I don't have it on github yet. But I use it on one of my websites: c2064.org/spielplatz (Just go to "Galerie" and you have some examples -- click one, then right click, show source). That are one page implementations. Make sure you change all links that refer zu something with c2064.org

Comment: Thanks. I will see what I can learn from your and add it to mine: https://github.com/thinsoldier/khanacademyJS/commits/master/khanProcessing.js

Comment: Looks nice. I'm sure I'll get some ideas from it ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you reading that you can change it? That would be old documentation that we need to fix.

Use the functions radians() and degrees() to convert. For instance:

**Code:**

```
// Get the sine of 90 degrees
float s = sin(radians(90));
```

Comment: Here: http://processingjs.org/reference/rotate_/ "Parameters angle float: angle of rotation specified in radians or degrees depending on the *current angle mode*

Comment: I would need such a function so that programs written for the KA live editor easily can be tranfered to processing.js. Otherwise I had to use radians in Khan Academy also which might be less transparent for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question and had me scratching my head quite a bit. But from what I can tell, this is simply a typo in the reference. Standard Processing.js does not have an `angleMode` function. This is easy to confirm by doing a ctrl+f in the [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/processing-js/processing-js/v1.4.8/processing.js).

So, why is it in the reference? The `angleMode` function does turn up in two places:

- [p5.js](http://p5js.org/) has an [angleMode](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/angleMode) function. This is like Processing.js, only heavier on the JavaScript side.
- [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) has an [angleMode](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/anglemode-processingjs/2350518561) variable. They appear to have added it on top of standard Processing.js.

My guess would be that Khan Academy and Processing.js share some development roots. They were both worked on by [John Resig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Resig). So some of the initial code (and documentation) was probably a copy-paste job. At some point, `angleMode` was included in the documentation, but not in the source.

You could submit an issue for it on the Processing.js website's [GitHub](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js.github.io/issues).

Processing.js only supports radians (although you can easily convert using the `radians()` and `degrees()` functions, but Khan Academy uses degrees by default. So you might consider modifying any subsequent Khan Academy code to use radians instead of degrees:

```
void setup(){
   angleMode = "radians";
}
```

Then any code you take from there will be compatible with standard Processing.js, minus that `angleMode` line.